# Merge Hive tables using RJDBC package

Tags: r, rjdbc

I am using RJDBC package to connect to Hive.

```
library(rJava)
library(RJDBC)
-
-
-
conn <- dbConnect(drv, "jdbc:hive2://ip:port","***", "****")
```

After getting connected I type this command to see the list of tables:

```
dbListTables(conn)

[1] "m_11"                     "m_12"                    
 [3] "m_16"                     "m_18"                    
 [5] "m_19"                     "m_20"
```

Other command i.e.

```
dbGetTables (conn, "m_11")
TABLE_CAT TABLE_SCHEM TABLE_NAME TABLE_TYPE REMARKS
1                report m_11      TABLE    <NA>
```

But when I want to read table it shows error as "Table not found":

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from m_11")
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select * from m_11 (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'm_11')
```

Also,

```
d <- dbReadTable(conn, "m_11")
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for SELECT * FROM "m_11" (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: ParseException line 1:14 cannot recognize input near '"m_11"' '<EOF>' '<EOF>' in join source)
```

I want to know following commands:

a) How to read table i.e. m_11
b) Merge two table i.e m_11 & m_12 by "Consm_ID"

Is there any other easy alternative to get it done in R.

Answer (score 0):

you should append the database name to the table name to access it. i think rjdbc has "default" db as default.

```
dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from dbName.m_11")
```

Also, you should be using hive querys to merge or join two tables, instead of merging them after you get the data-frames in R, as the data source (here hive) would be mostly smarter than join/merge functions in R as datasources as more knowledge about how the data is laid out.

Comment: is it still giving out the same "table not found" error? did you include all the required jars for jdbc connectivity?

Comment: dbGetQuery(conn, "select * from default.m_11")                     
                                                                                                          Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
  Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select * from default.metric_561 (Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10001]: Line 1:14 Table not found 'm_11')

Comment: dbExistsTable(conn, "m_11")
[1] TRUE